# How to insert parameters into a MongoDB eloquent aggregation function?

Tags: json, laravel, mongodb, aggregation-framework, laravel-blade

I have the following code in my controller.

```
public function show(Request $request) {

       $data = Book::raw(function ($collection, Request $request) {

          return $collection->aggregate([
             [
                '$match' => [
                   'T.HD.HD02' => ['$eq' => $request->date]
                ],
             ],
          ]);
       });
  
    }
```

**Blade**

```
 <form action="{{ route('geomongo.show') }}"  method="POST">
        @csrf

        <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="20220522">

        <input type="submit" />
        
 </form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::controller(BookController::class)->group( function() {   
    Route::get('dashboard/geomongo', 'index')->name('geomongo.index');
    Route::post('dashboard/geomongo', 'show')->name('geomongo.show');   
});
```

**Error**:

[image: ArgumentCountError]

I am receiving parameters from my Blade file and I want to insert them into this function. The name **T.HD.HD02** refers to a date entered by the user.

The variable *Request $request* doesn't even work inside the function.

How can I make it recognize the Request parameters?

Comment: Are you sure the date property is present in request? try providing a default value in case if doesn't.

Comment: I have updated the file...

Comment: `Book::raw(function ($collection) use ($request)` there's no 2nd parameter in the callback of the `raw` function

Comment: Using the `use ($request)` does not generate any error but I do not get any results. The table is empty.

Comment: The Eloquent `raw` method simply creates an [expression](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Expression.html), it doesn't create a query as such which is why you're not seeing anything. What are you actually trying to do here? What do you want to do with `date`?